# How to view installed Northwind database?

Tags: sql-server, database, northwind

I have installed a sample database, specifically Northwind from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b6y4c7s.aspx.

After installing the .msi file, I dont see any Northwind database in my local sql express server when using SQL Server management studio. Am i missing a step? Do i have to run some script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06616212-0356-46A0-8DA2-EEBC53A68034&displaylang=en):

```
After downloading SQL2000SampleDb.msi, extract the sample database scripts by 
double-clicking SQL2000SampleDb.msi. SQL2000SampleDb.msi will extract the 
database scripts and this readme file into this 
default folder:

C:\SQL Server 2000 Sample Databases
```

So it seems to me you have to go to that folder and execute the SQL files installed there for the database to be created.

Comment: current download page doesn't even tell you where it puts the files - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=06616212-0356-46a0-8da2-eebc53a68034&displayLang=en

Answer (score 1):

you don't mention which msi file, but most of them seem to relate to a sample database.

Which database software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

From the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06616212-0356-46A0-8DA2-EEBC53A68034&displaylang=en) on the page you linked to:

> After downloading SQL2000SampleDb.msi,
>   extract the sample database scripts by
>   double-clicking SQL2000SampleDb.msi.
>   SQL2000SampleDb.msi will extract the
>   database scripts and this readme file
>   into this default folder: C:\SQL
>   Server 2000 Sample Databases

I didn't download it to see what gets extracted, but I'm betting there's a script or two that you can run to create the database.  Probably a *.sql, that you can open and run in a query window.

**EDIT:** I just downloaded and extracted.  It looks like all you need to do is execute the contents of instnwnd.sql (which should be in C:\SQL Server 2000 Sample Databases).  Open a new query window (in SSMS etc.), load the file, and press F5.